# MySQL get view dump

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a view which returns quite a lot of data. Right now, the view is loaded into a file like this:

```
SELECT * FROM view INTO OUTFILE /path/to/file.tmp;
```

Then it is loaded from that file to a table:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE /path/to/file.tmp INTO TABLE table;
```

And then mysqldump is used to create a dump of this table (in fact multiple tables, the first two steps are repeated more times and then mysqldump is run).

Is there a better way to do this? Ideally I would like to do this without having to save anything to a file. Is it possible just to create an sql dump of a data from view with a single statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not with mysqldump. mysqldump just exports the view definitions, not the data.

You can reduce what you've got by a step by using the [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-select.html) syntax. That is, insert directly into your new table from the view. Then mysqldump that. No need for the file.tmp file. Something like

```
INSERT INTO table SELECT * FROM view;
```

Another possibility is to write a program that you use in place of mysqldump for exporting views as if it were a table. That program could examine the view structure and export data in a format compatible with mysqldump.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table (col1, col2, col3...)
    SELECT col1, col2, col3... FROM view
```

Should do the trick.